# Белая полоса в эмуляторе и на реальном устройстве Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image: Вот здесь появляется белая полоса (снизу)]

В разметке я нигде не указывал что там должна быть белая полоса. Как ее убрать? 
Вот разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#2b3238">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/corners"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="5"/>

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/corners"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="5"/>
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: у второй RelativeLayout попробуйте android:layout_height="match_parent" выставить

Comment: Тогда вот эти два поля сместятся в самый вверх экрана, а проблема останется

Comment: Какая тема используется для экрана? Попробуйте эту разметку на чистую активити поставить.

Comment: Я один не вижу никакой белой полосы?

Comment: @RawnaldGregoryErickson она есть это жирная белая полоса под всем контентом )) ее просто не видно из за того что она в конце и сливается с фоном сайта

Comment: Может ли быть, что белый фон это часть вашей активити? а разметку, которую вы сюда прилепили она от фрагмента, который в добавили в ту самую активити в контейнер с ограниченными размерами?

Comment: @Chaynik, разглядел. Разметка используется в ``Activity`` или во ``Fragment``?

Answer (score 1):

Берете вот этот замечательный тул
https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/hierarchy-viewer.html

И смотрите что за элемент, какой у него id, кто его хозяин и т.п.

Как определите откуда он взялся, можно начинать придумывать как от него избавиться.